# run cron jobs after loading ssh keys

Tags: bash, cron, profile

I have a linux machine on which I can run a script only after loading my sshkeys. I was able to add loading the keys via .bashrc and .bash_profile.
However, when I place the script on crontab, 
1) the script fails to load the profile and fails
2) the script runs in user's home directory but not the directory in which it is present

could any one help me to run the script as if I am logged in , loaded ssh keys and changed to a specific directory in which the script is present

Answer (score 0):

If you need an SSH key in a cron job you should remove the passphrase from that key (make sure it's a dedicated key used only for this job!) and add `-i /path/to/private_key` in the script.